# VBA function won't work in sql query: undefined function in query

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement, vba, undefined-function

I'm new to vba, so please excuse any vocabulary faux pas. My function is a very basic if statement. Runs great when debugging, but when I call it from my query, I get the dreaded "undefined function in query" error. Here's how I call it from **my query: color2: ItemColor([Color])**. The purpose is to take an inventory ID and pull out the color based on the ID code. This function will eventually be expanded for a large number of colors (more than 7), so I can't use the iif function in the query. I wanted to test the vba with just a few color options first.

Here's my code:

```
Public Sub ItemColor()

If [Color] = "01" Then
    MsgBox "natural"

  Else
     MsgBox "shell"
  End If
End Sub
```

**[Color] is a field in the same query.** [Color] is a string that has been pulled from the ID field using the Mid function. Can this vba function work on such a field?

Could it be because I'm using msgbox? I tried using Dim, (see code below) but it still didn't work. Maybe I had the syntax wrong?

```
Public Sub ItemColor()
Dim appearance As String

If [Color] = "01" Then
     appearance "natural"

  Else
     appearance "shell"
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a function to return a value, thus why the error states undefined function.  Try the below code if you want to hard code the return values based on a number provided:

```
Public function getColor(colorID) as string
    Dim strColor as string

    Select case colorID
        Case 1
            StrColor = "color name"
        Case 2
            Strcolor = "different color"
    End select
    Getcolor = strcolor
End function
```

Comment: I'm new to VBA, so select case is new to me. It looks like a better solution to my problem. The getColor(colorID) statement, is that supposed to refer to the field where my colorID string is located?

Comment: If you post a sample of your DB on a drive location i can find it, i can look at your tables and provide amore in depth solution.

Comment: I tried it and it works! Yay! Thanks for sharing your expertise.